# How can one classify data if the range of possible features is continuous/infinite?

Tags: classification

Imagine my instrument encodes colors using any/all possible wavelengths of light (not just the 3 features red, green, blue). Thus, it has an “infinite” number of features lying on a continuous spectrum. How could I do supervised learning to classify this type of data?

Comment: If you really had an infinite number of features, how are you actually *storing* the data?  Up to this point in history, I believe humanity has developed the ability to store and collect only a finite amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hypothetical.  In the real finite world this sounds like the "classification of multispectral image data" and is common in remote sensing.  Do an internet search and you will find plenty of literature, blogs, videos, books, and software.